# How to convert string path with \ to \\?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, electron

I use jquery to get the path of out an html img element like this:

```
path = $("#img_elemnt_id).attr('src')
```

It gives me a string

```
path = "C:\User\pic.jpg"
```

I need to use that string in a function but it only works if the path is like this

```
path ="C:\\User\\pic.jpg"
```

Any idea how to do this?

UPDATE: YOUR ANSWERS DO NOT WORK.

```
path = "C:\\User\\pic.jpg"
```

works in the function but your answers do not work.

```
path = "C:\User\pic.jpg"
path = path.replace('\\,'\\\\')
console.log(path)
```

outputs

```
C:Userpic.jpg
```

Comment: Have you tried using the function with the retrieved `path`? It should work as the `'\'` are already escaped and ready to go.

Comment: no it does not work

Comment: Can you provide the code of the function?

Comment: `I need to use that string in a function...` <= What function? Did you write this function because if so then you nee do rewrite it to be correct. There is no reason to have to pass in literal double backslashes for directory separator characters.

Comment: My downvote is because i was on your other question (which was very related), which you deleted shortly afterwards. I don't intend to deal with simple things that just get deleted shortly after the question was created.

Comment: @ASDFGerte I don't think that's a good reason to downvote this newly created post.

Comment: You should not have C:\ inside of an `src` element. Use a proper `file://` path.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir it is also because the issue is simple and no attempt was made (which is a proper reason). However, not thinking before asking a question, getting a few comments, deleting it after less than five minutes, then asking a new, very related question, is wasting time of me and everyone who is reading and attempting to deal with the questions.

Comment: @tadman I guess it's the other way around: there should be no `file://` in the path (giving that `src`s most like have it). See OP's example!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir e.g. regarding the newest edits, i already posted a comment in his last (related and currently deleted) question, that backslashes in JS need to be escaped in strings. Now the same issue appears here again. I am not a repeater.

Comment: @ASDFGerte I have no control over what string jquery gives me.

Comment: @ASDFGerte No body is forcing you to repeat anything.

Comment: @fred.h Are there any `"file://"` in the paths?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir enjoy answering this then. I wish you the best of luck. You will need it.

Comment: NO THERE IS NOT

Comment: A) Chill out, all-caps is just annoying. B) You need to give us an example of what you're trying to do including specific HTML and JavaScript. We're just trying to help, but you're not being especially forthcoming with details.

Answer (score 5):

```js
var path = 'C:\\User\\pic.jpg';
console.log(path);
path = path.replace(/\\/g,'\\\\');
console.log(path);
```

If path is having single backslash characters, those will be considered as an escape sequence along with the character(s) following them.

Answer (score 1):

Use [replace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

```
path = path.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\");
```

I edited to include the global 'g' flag, to make it a correct solution.

Comment: The only real problem with this is code that it only replaces the first encountered occurrence. For a directory separator that would not work unless you called it in a loop.

Comment: I added the required global flag to correct the issue, thank you @Igor

Answer (score 1):

The flaw here is that you're declaring your string wrong in the first place:

```js
path = "C:\User\pic.jpg"
console.log(path)
// => C:Userpic.jpg
```

It's *already* broken by this point. You must express it correctly in the first 
place or the backslash will break things:

```js
path = "C:\\User\\pic.jpg"
console.log(path)
// => C:\User\pic.jpg
```

This is because `\U` and `\p` get interpreted as *literal* `u` and `p`. Beyond that point there is no recovering the "missing" characters because this is how JavaScript's string syntax works. The second version uses `\\` which is *literal backslash* and that avoids the issue.

If you're pulling this from an HTML element it's a different story. The backslashes should be properly encoded if and only if you properly supplied the `src` attribute in the first place.

If you use `file://` path specifiers you can use regular slash instead of backslash and avoid all of this mess which I *strongly encourage you to do*.

**Edit**:

Now if you have no control over the `src` attribute, which is where this should be set properly in the first place, you could try and fix it like:

```
path = 'path:///' + $('id').attr('src').replace(/\\/, '/');
```